# How do I make improvements with my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

```css
html,body{
background-color: #5f5f5f;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.container{
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 30px;
}

header{
background-color: #000000;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

header h1{
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
}

.nav {
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
list-style: none;
padding: 10px 100px;
}

.nav li {
display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li a{
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.nav li a:hover{
color: #D3D3D3;
border: 1px solid white;
}

.nav li.active a{
border: 1px solid white;
}

.banner-image {
width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> GWS News</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Grass World Sport News</h1>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="file:///Users/rarichenjoseph/Desktop/GWS%202/Website.html#">World Cup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="banner">
            <img class="banner-image" src=img/banner1.jpeg>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

I want to fix up my navigation bar but do not know how to do it.

Improvement I want to make are:

1. How do I change the font colour to white (I have tried font: #ffffff as you can see in the coding)?
2. How do I make the link spaced out?
3. How do I move the links to the very right (float does not seem to be working as you can see in the coding)?
4. How do I make the font bigger for the navigation bar (font: 20px does not seem to be working as you can see in the coding)?
5. How do I make the title "Grass World Sport News" bigger?

Comment: This is very broad and asking to do it for you. I will for this instance, but I'm going to point you towards some resources so you can learn these fundamentals yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I change the font colour to white (I have tried font: #ffffff as you can see in the coding)?**

The problem is your selector, should be `ul.nav li a` and not `.nav ul li a`

**How do I make the link spaced out?**

Just add to link element a left margin (since you want it to float right):

```
ul.nav li {
   margin-left: 1rem // for example
}
```

**How do I move the links to the very right (float does not seem to be working as you can see in the coding)?**

The float is working correctly but you have a max width on parent container so it gets only to the far right of the container. If you want it to the right of the window remove max-width.

```
div.container{
margin: 0;
padding: 0 30px;
}
```

**How do I make the font bigger for the navigation bar (font: 20px does not seem to be working as you can see in the coding)?**

Same problem as number 1. Just set the selector to be `ul.nav li a`

**How do I make the title "Grass World Sport News" bigger?**

If you mean a bigger font just set a higher font-size.

```
header h1 {
   // for example
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad, and looking at the code it appears much was either copy/pasted from another site expecting the same results which is not how coding works.

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/codespent/pen/BVXyWO

To answer your questions:

1. To change font color, you use `color: #fff` in the parent rule.
2. Spacing can be done in multiple ways, but just learn box model before you start playing with anything so you know why you're using paddings or margin.
3. Moving the links to the right is also contextual, there's many ways you can do so, but you need to understand why you're doing it this way. `text-align:right;` may work, but **Flexbox** is recommended.
4. `font` [is an outdated property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp). You may use `font-size:20px;` to change the font size.
5. This is also a broad question as there are many ways that are contextual to how you feel is best.

To understand these fundamentals, I highly recommend taking [freeCodeCamp's Basic CSS courses](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/basic-css) and as well, you should see [StackOverflow's "How to Ask" knowledge object](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to grasp how you should be presenting your questions when coming here for help.

Comment: That's not true at all. I've watched multiple youtube videos and taken idea from all of it and put it together. I've had no knowledge about coding before I done this and my teacher doesn't teach me anything because he doesn't know. I have to learn everything by myself.

Comment: Font is a property, according to brackets it is.

Comment: Font is, yes, I should rephrase; [Its not a proper property to today's standards](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp).